# How do write LINQ query to do recursion?

Tags: .net, linq

If I had an object called `Thing` that had a property `Id` and `Children` where `Children` is essentially a list of `Thing`. It would look like this:

```
Public Class Thing
    Public Property Id As Guid
    Public Property Children As List(Of Thing)
End Class
```

Now Given an existing `List(Of Thing)`, let's called it `aList` for the sake of this example, how could I use LINQ to recursively loop throw each Thing and Children to find out if an Item exist in the entire hierarchy?

`Dim aList As List(Of Thing)`

In order words, given an ID, how would I write the LINQ statement against `aList` to see if that ID exists anywhere in the  hierarchy?

Hope you can help me and thanks in advance for your contribution!

Comment: Write a recursive function that accepts `IEnumerable<Thing>` and the `Thing` to match.

Comment: Just curious, this is vb.Net code.  Do you want only VB solutions?  If so, you should add the [tag:vb.net] tag.

Comment: Would be something like `aList.single(function(x) x.Id = refId)` wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq isn't designed for recursion and doesn't handle it well.  There are ways to shoehorn it but a standard recursive function would be much cleaner and easier to debug:

```
Public Function IsInTree(Thing theThing, IEnumerable(Of Thing) tree) As Boolean
    If tree.Any(Function(t) t.Id = theThing.Id) Then 
        IsInTree = True
    ElseIf Children Is Not Nothing Then
        IsInTree = tree.Any(Function(t) IsInTree(theThing, t.Children))
    Else
        IsInTree = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I fixed an issue. Take a look as it becomes available.